# Qualified imports, if possible with aliasing

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and have a package with no dots in the name: `test`. I now want to import stuff from this package into another Scala file, but I

- *do not want* to use wildcard imports because I want to prevent name clashes (so no `import test._`)
- *do not want* to import individual classes (so no `import test.{My, Manually, Maintained, List, Of, Classes}`)
- *do want* to keep `test` as a top level package (so no `package nested.test`)
- *would like to* alias the package to a shorter name (something like `import {test => t}`)

I have played around but was not successful until now. I compile with `scalac a.scala b.scala`:

- file `a.scala`

```scala
package test
class A {}
```

- experiments with file `b.scala`, none of which did work:

```scala
import _root_.{test => t} // error: _root_ cannot be imported
class A extends t.A {}
```

```scala
import _root_.test // error: _root_ cannot be imported
class A extends test.A {}
```

```scala
import test // error: . expected
class A extends test.A {}
```

```scala
import test.A // warning: imported `A` is permanently hidden by definition of class A
class A extends A {} // error: illegal cyclic reference involving class A
```

```scala
import {test => t} // error: identifier expected but '{' found.
                   // error: . expected
class A extends t.A {}
```

In python I could achieve what I want like this

```py
import test as t
class A(t.A): pass
```

and in Haskell I could do

```hs
import qualified Test as T
type A = T.A
```

**Question**: Can something like this be achieved in Scala?  What could I do to get close to this?

Comment: Using `test` as a library name is a bad idea. Just invent your own domain name and use that as the prefix for your library code.

Comment: For the record, I [reported this](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12329).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `test` is the fully qualified name of your package you don't need to import it at all. Just use it:

```scala
class A extends test.A
```

Going a bit more into detail. In Scala a package is available by name simply if it is present on the compilation classpath. And it is the build tool that decides what is on the classpath (or yourself, if you use commandline scalac, which I wouldn't recommend but for the most trivial experiments).

Imports in Scala (and most—if not all—other languages on the JVM) are not really about telling the compiler or interpreter which "module" you want to use, like in Python. Their main purpose is to allow you to use the short name of classes and objects (`Foo`, `bar`) instead of their fully qualified names (`org.example.project.Foo`, `org.example.project.bar`).

Aliasing a package that's in the `_root_` namespace unfortunately doesn't seem to be possible in Scala 2. In Scala 3 `import _root_.{test => t}` actually appears to work. At least in the preview snapshot I am currently using.

Comment: This works but I believe OP want to rename `test` to `t`.

Comment: Based on his examples it looks like using `test` as-is would be acceptable but not ideal. But renaming `test` (the ideal) simply isn't possible currently.

Comment: Yeah I get that, is there any reason why that is not possible. Sounds like a bug to me, would it be worth reporting?

Comment: I wouldn't really call it a bug, though I'm not sure if it's an oversight or intentional. It might still be a good feature request though. Or just good to report in order to discover if it's intentional or not.

Comment: It turns out this _is_ actually possible in Scala 3, so then perhaps it may be kind of a bug/oversight.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks Jasper. - @Lucas would you like to report it yourself and paste the link of the report here? Since you are the one that needs the feature it feels good to be you; otherwise, I may report it in a couple of days. - You can report it [here](https://github.com/scala/bug).

Comment: The use case is if test is shadowed, you'd normally use _root_.test, but for the short form, you need rename on import. I see the restriction was added a long time ago Xmas 2007, intentionally.